# Python/Ubuntu multicast damaged packets

Tags: python, opencv, udp, multicast

Basically I have an application that receives UDP stream over multicast, But i have problem when i try to save received mpeg format into chunks every one second and then i read first frame using opencv2 library to save as images every one second, but problem is that when i connect same cable to my Dell inspiron (Ubuntu Desktop) it works perfect saves every frame without any lose or damage, but when i try to run my python code on server (Dell Poweredge with Ubuntu Server) every 8 frames from 10 are damaged. I don't really understand what is the problem, when i dump video file for 1 hour for example Video player opens it and it seems everything works fine but again when i try extract images i'm getting same problem. anyone can help me to understand why should dell inspiron with Ubuntu Desktop receives multicast stream without lose and ubuntu server doesn't? we tried on 4 different machines and same problem, but again from my laptop it works.

I don't know what is the problem, first time i thought that it was sysctl configuration problem, udp buffer size... etc but, results are same every time.

Here is Multicast socket listener:

```
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
sock.bind((args.ip_address, args.port))
mreq = struct.pack(">4sl", socket.inet_aton(args.ip_address), socket.INADDR_ANY)
sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_IP, socket.IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, mreq)
```

and opencv first frame dumper from chunk files(chunk files are about 2mb of size 1 second video):

```
 def run(self):
        try:
            cv2c = cv2.VideoCapture(self.base_file.name)

            if cv2c.isOpened():
                success, image = cv2c.read()
            else:
                success = False

            cap2c = os.path.basename(self.base_file.name)
            cap2c = os.path.splitext(cap2c)[0]

            if success:
                success, image = cv2c.read()
                cv2.imwrite(image_dir + cap2c + ".jpg", image)

            cv2c.release()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        except OSError as error:
            sys.stderr.write('Error dumping image frame error:' + error.message)
```

Comment: That's the thing with UDP. There's no guarantee that the package is going to get on the other side with perfect integrity.

Comment: but on laptop it works perfect with same cable same stream same place everything is the same, i used same hdd on another PC and this system works fine on other pc too, but fresh ubuntu install doesn't :(